# how can i use perl to calculate the frequency of a variable

Tags: perl

```
PASS AC=0;AF=0.048;
AN=2;
ASP;
BaseQRankSum=0.572;
CAF=[0.9605,.,0.03949];
CLNACC=RCV000111759.1,RCV000034730
```

I'm a new here.I want to know how to match CAF = [0.9605,.,0.03949] using regular expression,thank you.

Comment: I don't see the relation between the title and the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: sorry ,my english is poor. I  want to calculate the second number in CAF to divide the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) {
    if (
        /^CAF=   # start of line, then literal 'CAF='
         \[      # literal '['
         [^\]]+  # 1+ characters different from ']'
         \];     # closing ']'
         /x
      )
    {
        print;
    }
}
```

The `/x` modifier allows for linebreaks and comments in the regex (to improve readability).

Or, as a one liner:

```
perl -ne 'print if (/^CAF=\[[^\]]+\];/);' <your_file>
```

This prints the complete lines containing the desired pattern.

Comment: and i want to know how to calculate the second number in vcf to divide the first one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the documentation for Perl regex. What you are asking doesn't look more complex than a beginner could match having read the docs:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html